# Is this HTTP Header wrong?

Tags: http, http-headers, bittorrent

I am trying to write a torrent downloader and needed to work out how to contact a tracker. I used the Fiddler2 program to intercept a tracker request sent from Vuze to it's tracker.

In the message sent (shown below), the Connection header is declared twice with different values.

Is this a correct use of the Connection header?
What does Connection: keep-alive do?

```
GET /announce?info_hash=0Z%22...&azver=3&azas=12576 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Azureus 4.7.0.2;Windows 7;Java 1.6.0_31
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: tracker.update.vuze.com:6969
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From RFC2616 section 4.2:

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present
>   in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header
>   field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST
>   be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one
>   "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the
>   message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each
>   separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same
>   field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation
>   of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the
>   order of these field values when a message is forwarded.

Edit:

According to section 14.10, Connection is such a field-name, so **having multiple Connection headers is technically correct**.

From 14.10 the grammar production for the Connection header is `Connection = "Connection" ":" 1#(connection-token)`, so one or more comma separated tokens **are** valid.

In practise however, it may be that the second Connection header will be ignored, and thus the web server will expect to close the underlying TCP connection once the response has been sent.

For HTTP 1.1 the default mode is for the server to keep the underlying TCP connection open for subsequent requests, although many servers will limit the total number of requests made before closing the connection anyway.

Comment: You are wrong, Connection headres are defined as a comma-separated list.

Comment: Thanks.  You are right; I've clarified my answer based on the grammar production in the RFC.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 1.1 allows multiple Connection headers. The semantics of multiple such headers are defined to be the same as a single header with all values joined together with commas, e.g.

```
Connection: close
Connection: keep-alive
```

is the same as:

```
Connection: close,keep-alive
```

So technically, these headers are fine. However, I will herewith predict without having made some experiments that there will be a lot of servers out there (especially not so well tested ones such as torrent trackers) who will ignore either one of these headers.

Now, the deeper problem is that "keep-alive" is some http 1.0 extension, and kind of contradicts the "close", so I guess this combination is simply a bug in the torrent client. I guess most trackers will not allow persistent connections anyway, though, so I think the bets way to proceed i to only have a single "Connection: close" header.

Answer (score 0):

Its weird to have 2 Connection Header Fields. I think you can only expect a non-deterministic behavior as the handling of this case depends solely on the implementation of the web server.
It might end up with any of the 2 in (let's say) the hashmap storing the fields.

Basically, keep alive means that the browser is allowed to maintain the connection to the server and to keep retrieving images, scripts over it. Usually this is not the case. Normally, a Connection to a web server is closed after the request was given a response.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection: Close
```

means that after the the request has completed close the connection.

```
Connection: keep-alive
```

means keep the connection open for future request.

You should only have one Connection parameter.

So therefore the HTTP header is not correct.